# error JavaScript critical error ...: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am getting error below while using ajax in asp.net MVC, and I have no idea what's wrong with it!

> JavaScript critical error at line 161, column 101 in
>   http://localhost:50474/Home/Products\n\nSCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Here is my View:

```
 <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CreateOrder(@pr.ProId)" role="button">خرید</a>
```

Here my Action in controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateOrder(Guid productId)
        {
            Order or = new Order();
            or.Number = 1;
            or.ProductId = productId;
            or.SessinId = Request.UserHostAddress;
            int proprice = db.Products.Where(c => c.ProId == productId).Select(c => c.Price).FirstOrDefault();
            or.TotalPrice = proprice * 1;
            db.Orders.Add(or);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int count = (db.Orders.Where(c => c.SessinId == or.SessinId).Select(c => 
            c.OrderId)).Count();
            Session["ShopcartCount"]= count;
            db.Dispose();

            return RedirectToAction("Products", "Home");

           }
```

And here is ajax code:

```
   <script>
        function CreateOrder(productId) {
         $.ajax({

             url: "/Home/CreateOrder/" + productId,
             type: "post"
         }).done(function (result) {
             $("#shopcart").html(result);
         });
     }

     $(function () {
         $("#shopcart").load("/Home/ShopCartCount");
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: What code is at `line 161, column 101` of the JavaScript file? Please show that too.

Comment: this part of view:  onclick="CreateOrder(@pr.ProId)"

Comment: Try this way onclick="CreateOrder(@(pr.ProdId))"

Comment: ProId nullable?

Comment: @jishansiddique no, it is not null. it works i,m sure

Comment: So you are passing `GUID` Javascript consider as string object expect numeric value pass direclry. Please check this `<p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CreateOrder('@pr.ProId')" role="button">خرید</a>`

Comment: @jishansiddique Thank you very much, the error is not shown anymore, but it's not working

Comment: In my demo, I have checked and after that, I'm telling you may be something amiss with your code can you please check? or please check this link https://dotnetfiddle.net/h05cci

Comment: @jishansiddique I've seen it, I just changed ajax function to yhis and it worked!!          `function DeleteOrder(orderid) {

            var value = orderid;
            $.ajax({
                data: { orderid: value },
             url: '@Url.Action("DeleteOrder")',
             type: "Get"
            })
     }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this way you got this error

Here working example first button your code and second button working fine.
[Click here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h05cci)

> View

```
<p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CreateOrder('@pr.ProId')" role="button">خرید</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @jishan siddique posted in his answer, you need to use single quotes `' '` around your model property `'@pr.ProId'` like `CreateOrder('@pr.ProId)'` instead of `CreateOrder(@pr.ProId)` for the Razor view to recognise it.